# How to Update Two table Data one after other In codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

[image: I create a model to update plan data but now with that i want to update the vendor_plan_task_mapping data because i use the plan data with vendor so when i update the plan after creating a vendor with some plan the updated plan data can't come to vendor task status mapping data hear i create a model for updating plan i have to update task_status_mapp table to be update...]

how to update plan with vendor_plan_task_status_mapp table.

the model  for plan update is

```
public function updatePlanData(){

    $planId = $this->input->post('plan_id');
    $data = array(

                    'plan_title' => $this->input->post('plan_title'),
                    'plan_price' => $this->input->post('plan_price'),
                    'plan_desc'     => $this->input->post('plan_desc')

                );

    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $this->db->update('tbl_plan', $data);


    $this->db->where('plan_id',$planId);
    $this->db->delete('plan_task_mapping');



    foreach ($this->input->post('task_id') as $key => $value)

     {
        $data2 = array(

        'plan_id' => $planId,
        'task_id'   => $value

        );
     // echo "Index {$key}'s value is {$value}.";
           $this->db->insert('plan_task_mapping', $data2);
     }

//-------- HEAR I NEED A CODE TO UPDATE The V_T_S_M table-----------

}
```

after 1st table update i want to update the data in vendr_task_status_mapping table?????

Comment: Never insert, update or delete in a foreach. Use insert_batch.

Comment: ok but hear the i update the data of 1st tabel then i want that updated data in the other table.... what should i do sir???

Comment: @Deep Parekh  sir any help???

Comment: Hello, till your code which you have uploaded here you have done right ? now you want to update V_T_S_M table ?

Comment: sir this plan data used in the vendor table so this is change the vendor table get errors...  hear the code only update vedding_plan_task_status now i want to update VTSM table...

Comment: but there is no table with vedding_plan_task_status ??? i think u mean vedding_plan_task_mapping !! u updated this table and now you want to update VTSM table ?

Comment: actually you got it correct ... but sir i use this id in other table so how i update that data...   bcoze updating this data causing error in that table because the existing id will be deleted in that table.

Comment: yes exactly you have deleted the previous records so the db can not find that id. OK i got. for example the old id is 1 then in VTSM table you have one status for 1 id right or is it possible multiple status for on id(1->plan task mapping id) ?

Comment: may be correct sir...   for solving this problem i decide to update the date from plan  controller but i don't know how to get a vendor data ??(because i delete the plan id and insert new id for updated plan and now the vendor table has old plan data so how i get that??? )

Comment: see my code !!! feel free to ask anything :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84672/discussion-between-deep-parekh-and-ankit-suthar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN THIS ANSWER YOU GET AN ERROR IF YOU CHANGE THE PLAN BUT USING THIS CODE YOU HAVE TO SIMPLY EDIT AND UPDATE IT ANGIN AND THIS MODEL IS CREATE A NEW ID FOR YOUR TASK AND INSERT IT AGAIN.

```
 public function vendorUpdateModel($data)

       {
         $vendor_id = $this->input->post('vendor_id');
         $data = array(
           'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
           'plan_id' => $this->input->post('plan_id'),
           'city_id' => $this->input->post('city_id'),
           'business_name' => $this->input->post('business_name'),
           'owner_name' => $this->input->post('owner_name'),
           'contact_no1' => $this->input->post('contact_no1'),
           'contact_no2' => $this->input->post('contact_no2'),
           'vendor_email' => $this->input->post('vendor_email'),
           'subscription_date' => $this->input->post('subscription_date'),
           'vendor_description' => $this->input->post('vendor_description'),
           'vendor_address' => $this->input->post('vendor_address')

           );

       $this->db->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
       $this->db->update('vendor',$data);

       $this->db->where('vendor_id',$vendor_id);
       $this->db->delete('vendor_task_status_mapping');

       $this->db->select('task_mapp_id');
       $this->db->where('plan_id',$this->input->post('plan_id'));

       $query = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');

       foreach($query->result() as $row)

       {
       $data2 = array(

       'task_mapp_id' => $row->task_mapp_id,
       'vendor_id'  => $vendor_id,
          'task_status'  => '0'

          );

             $this->db->insert('vendor_task_status_mapping', $data2);
        }
          return;
         }
```

Comment: thanks... it's done..  but i got error every time while i update the plan how i do it automatically update the vendor data according to plan task????

Answer (score 1):

If you added one field in plan_task_mapping table for add unique number then... As you mention your code:

```
$unique=array();
foreach ($this->input->post('task_id') as $key => $value)
 {
   $no=rand(0, 15);
    $data2 = array(
    'unique_no'=>$no,
    'plan_id' => $planId,
    'task_id'   => $value
    );
   $unique[] = $no; //store no in array to use it.

 // echo "Index {$key}'s value is {$value}.";
       $this->db->insert('plan_task_mapping', $data2);
 }
```

Before deleting plan_task_mapping table data. fetch that data.

```
function select()
{
    $this->db->where('plan_id',$planId);
    $Q = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');
    if($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Then delete the data as you mention in you code:

```
 $this->db->where('plan_id',$planId);
 $this->db->delete('plan_task_mapping');
```

Then delete that old data from VTSM table:

```
 $this->db->where('vendor_plan_task_mapping_id',$data[0]['id']); //this data[0]['id'] come form select(). change field name if required.
 $this->db->delete('VTSM');
```

Here fetch that new inserted data by that unique no:  //which we stored it in array.

```
foreach($unique as $u_no)
{
   $this->db->where('unique_no',$u_no);
    $Q = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');
    if($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row1)
        {
            $plan[] = $row1;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $plan;
}
```

In above code we have fetched that new inserted data to get their id to insert status.

Now inserting status:

```
foreach($plan as $a)
{
    $Sdata=array(
        "plan_task_mapping_id"=>$a['id'], //this is new id change name if required
      "status"="your new status");
      $this->db->insert('VTSM',$Sdata);

}
```

Comment: no sir the updated id only update single data i have many id as the task in the mapping table

Comment: you have to insert one unique number in plan_task_mapping table while inserting new data in loop. so that we can use this unique number when we required.

Comment: yes sir i solved it..  i put the code in vendor insert. while inserting a vendor i update the data..  i got some error if i previously change the same plan which i choose in vendor ..so i have to edit and insert it again. !  otherwise i done it.

Comment: sir the 1st answer   is what i done but i have to edit the entry every time as plan change ..  can you help me to update it automatic . hope u understand what i say

Comment: i use plan task for each vendor..  means every vendor has it's own plan and that selecting the plan vendor get some task (plan task). now when enter some vendor has selected plan1 (plan1 hase 2task) so vendor get 2 plantask.   now if i update the plan task (i change it like i choose 3task over two 2 task) so after updating that data they get all there new id. i use that previous id in vendor so i have that updated id in vendor but i don't have it so i update the vendor data again so i get that latest plan task id in my vendor task mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->db->insert_batch();` instead of inserting in `foreach loop`.
Check at this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329121000/https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) how to use it.

Comment: i can't use it because i want to update 2 table but in my system i have to update 1st table then i take data from that updated table and use that data to update another table. ok sir

Comment: i use the updated table id which is may be not a single entity, i know how to fetch last inserted id but hear i want the all updated id ???